# Table row content in modal popup

Tags: javascript

I am using Twitter Bootstrap on my page.
In search result table I want to dispaly all row content.

I have something like this:

```
$('.more-detail').click(function(){
var row = $(this).parent().parent();
var data = [];
$(row).find('td').not(0).each(function(){
data.push($(this).text());

});
console.log(data);
});
```

In can see all data in console.log, but how to move this to modal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare bootstrap modal element in your document:

```
<div id="result-modal" class="modal hide fade" style="display:none">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;      </button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          .....
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="result-content">
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then modify your javascript code:

```
$('.more-detail').click(function(){
  var row = $(this).parent().parent();
  var data = [];
  $("#result-content").empty();
  $(row).find('td').not(0).each(function(){
      data.push($(this).text());
      $("#result-content").append($(this).clone());
  });
  $('#result-modal').modal();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: and how to add table header to this view ?

Comment: Just use <thead> and put the table head content in tag. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 $('.more-detail').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    var data = [];
    $(row).find('td').not(0).each(function(){
    data.push($(this).text());

    });
    $(body).append('<div class="modal">' + data.join('') + '</div>');
    $('.modal').modal();
 });
```

Comment: and how to add table header to this view ?